# Looping through columns associated with another column to filter specific character codes based on both matching columns in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 15 million records. Each record has an ID, then 25 columns with between 1 and 25 event codes entered in the column. Each of those event code columns has a corresponding column in the dataset with a reason code. Everyone will have at least 1 event, but not everyone will have all 25 columns filled. I have provided a small example dataset below with just 3 event columns and 3 reason columns.

I am trying to write code in R that examines each event column and looks for a specific event code (for example, U78), then if it finds that code in the event column, it looks to the corresponding reason column for a specific reason code (for example, a 3 or a Y). If that corresponding reason code matches, I wish to retain that record in a new dataframe.

In the example data below, it would look at the row for ID 5 and see that Col_1 has U78, so it would then look at the corresponding reason column (Col_R_1) for either a "3" or a "Y". In this case, it is a 3, so I wish to keep that record.

In contrast, ID 22 has a "U78" in their event code, but because the reason code in the corresponding field is an "M", I would not wish to retain that record. ID 8 has no U78 event, so I also do not wish to retain that record.

The final dataset for this example would only retain ID 5, 6 and 343 because they all have a U78 event, with a corresponding reason code of either 3 or Y.

I can do the comparison with one pair of columns at a time using 25 case_when statements (basically, if Col_1 == "U78" & Col_1_R == "3" | Col_1_R "R") and then apply a filter on a flag I generated, but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way?

Thank you.

Example Dataset:

```
structure(list(ID = c(5, 6, 7, 8, 22, 343, 656, 595), Col_1 = c("U78", 
"D38", "T90", "T8", "U78", "G90", "G90", "Y88"), Col_2 = c("T90", 
"U78", NA, NA, NA, "T90", "B12", "T90"), Col_3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, "U78", NA, NA), Col_R_1 = c("3", "M", "R", "M", "M", 
"3", "3", "Y"), Col_R_2 = c("M", "Y", NA, NA, NA, "M", "M", "M"
), Col_R_3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Y", NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mapply` to iterate over groups of column-pairs: each `Col_#` paired with its `Col_R_#` column. I'll use `subset` here, though there are other ways to do this.

```r
fun <- function(col, rsn) col == "U78" & rsn %in% c("3", "Y")
mtx <- mapply(fun, 
              subset(quux, select=Col_1:Col_3),
              subset(quux, select=Col_R_1:Col_R_3))
mtx
#      Col_1 Col_2 Col_3
# [1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [6,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [7,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [8,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
quux[rowSums(mtx) > 0,]
# # A tibble: 3 × 7
#      ID Col_1 Col_2 Col_3 Col_R_1 Col_R_2 Col_R_3
#   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
# 1     5 U78   T90   NA    3       M       NA     
# 2     6 D38   U78   NA    M       Y       NA     
# 3   343 G90   T90   U78   3       M       Y
```

The use of `mapply` with the function `fun` is effectively the same as:

```r
fun(quux$Col_1, quux$Col_R_1)
fun(quux$Col_2, quux$Col_R_2)
fun(quux$Col_3, quux$Col_R_3)
```

And since we're using `mapply`, it simplifies those vectors into a matrix (I temporarily stored as `mtx`).

Comment: Thank you! This worked beautifully, is fast and is easily modifiable for some of my specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach.

1. Put your rules in a dataframe (I added an additional one to illustrate the use of multiple flags)

```
flags = data.frame(e=c("T90", "U78", "U78"), r=c("R", "3", "Y"))
```

2. Rearrange your data, and merge on those rows that meet the flags

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[dcast(
  melt(df,"ID",variable.name = "v")[
  ,`:=`(col=gsub("Col_(R_)?", "", v),v=fifelse(grepl("_R_",v),"r", "e"))],
  ID+col~v
)[flags, on=.(e,r), .(ID = unique(ID))], on=.(ID)]
```

Output:

```
      ID  Col_1  Col_2  Col_3 Col_R_1 Col_R_2 Col_R_3
   <num> <char> <char> <char>  <char>  <char>  <char>
1:     7    T90   <NA>   <NA>       R    <NA>    <NA>
2:     5    U78    T90   <NA>       3       M    <NA>
3:     6    D38    U78   <NA>       M       Y    <NA>
4:   343    G90    T90    U78       3       M       Y
```

In my example `flag` assumes that the same rules apply to different column pairs. Ie. If `U78` appears with reason `3` or `Y` or if event `T90` appears with reason `R`, and that these flags apply to all cols.  If these are column-specific, simply add a column called `col` to `flags`, to specify which reason/event combinations go with which columns.